# Switch statement not acting correctly

Tags: java, escaping, switch-statement

I'm trying to get this `switch` statement to work.

I ask for the user's birthday and they put it in the format `DD.MM.YYYY`. The `if` statement determines if they use the "." to separate it or one of my other symbols such as "/", " ".
The other symbols work fine, they enter the `switch` statement so if the user enters 15/07/1993 it will work fine and the month becomes July.
But when they enter 15.07.1993 it goes to the `default case` not the 7th case.

I assume it has got do with the escaped "."

```
("\\.")
```

This might be changing the value of it. Is there any way around it?
input is my scanner.

Any questions feel free to ask.

```
if(input.contains("\\."))
{
    String[] tokens = input.split("\\.");
    day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    intMonth = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
}

switch(intMonth)    
{       
    case 1: month = "January";
        break;  
    case 2: month = "Febuary";
        break;
    case 3: month = "March";
        break;
    case 4: month = "April";
        break;
    case 5: month = "May";
        break;
    case 6: month = "June";
        break;
    case 7: month = "July";
        break;
    case 8: month = "August";
        break;
    case 9: month = "September";
        break;
    case 10: month = "October";
        break;
    case 11: month = "November";
        break;
    case 12: month = "December";
        break;  
    default: month = "not valid";
        break;              
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a regular expression for `String.contains`.

According to the [method documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), you need to supply a `CharSequence` to `String.contains`, ie. you have to write `if (input.contains("."))` instead of `if (input.contains("\\."))`.